# Archestra IDE scripting. Start program with Process.StartInfo

Tags: wonderware

I have a script. It's not working. Without UserName and password everything is good. And must the logMessage show me "1" or not because of Secure type? LogMessage shows me just a "System.Security.SecureString" now.

```
pass = new System.Security.SecureString;
pass.AppendChar("1");
LogMessage(pass);
proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process;
proc.StartInfo.Username = "temp";
proc.StartInfo.Password = pass;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
proc.Start();
```

Comment: I'd assume you need to call `LogMessage(pass.ToString())` or equivalent. I doubt the LogMessage function knows what to do with a SecureString object type

Comment: It's not working. But logmessage is not my priority. My main aim is run "notepad.exe"